# Calculate date from last operation from 90 days after

Tags: python, django

I need to calculate 90 day after last operation in user's cart!

I have model model ORDERING

```
class Order(DirtyFieldsMixin, models.Model):
    ...
    items_add_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

my task is. Track the date when user added last item in his own cart and then, if past 90 days and user not added any more items in cart sent to him email.

I'm doing this

```
def cart_add(request):
    ...
    order.items_add_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    order.save()
    ...
```

But what and how should I act after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are struggling with but if you need to determine if its been 90 days then you would add a check:

```
#query for order
order = Order.get(xxx)
ninety  = datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=-90) 
if order.items_add_date < ninety:
    #send email
```

If you need to query for things older than 90 days:

```
order = Order.filter(items_add_date__lt=ninety)
```

Comment: What I need to get from Order model?

Comment: I dont understand?  Can you elaborate?

Comment: why "datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=-90)" instead of "datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(days=90)"?

Comment: Because you want to see if the last update date happened before 90 days ago.  Yours would be calculating 90 days in the future.

Comment: By doing `datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=-90)`, it evaluates to subtracting a negative delta, which is the same as adding a positive. Meaning yours will calculate 90 days in the future. The correct way would be to add a negative delta, or subtract a positive one. At least, that's how it is in 3.8

Answer (score 0):

I solved it so

```
srok = datetime.datetime.now()-timedelta(minutes=1)
user_unbuying = Order.objects.filter(items_add_date__lt=srok)

usr=[]

for unbus in user_unbuying:
    if unbus.customer.id not in usr:
        if unbus.customer is not None:
            if unbus.items_add_date is not None:
                usr.append(unbus.customer.id)
                #send mail
```